# Publish Github pages in Subdomain of custom domain error

Tags: github, subdomain, github-pages, cname, namecheap

It seems this is a fairly popular topic yet I still am unable to solve my problem. I have a domain `http://www.illiteratibooksandcoffee.com/` which points to my `illiterati` repo on github. Now I created a subdomain `theotherspace.illiteratibooksandcoffee.com/`, which points to my `theotherspace` repo in github. My issue, when I test the site as `username.github.io/theotherspace` it works fine but after setting up `theotherspace.illiteratibooksandcoffee.com/` my page will not render and I get the following errors.

This on firefox console:

[image]

This is on the chrome console:

[image]

Below my configuration on github:

[image]

My CNAME record also seems to be set up correctly:

[image]

I am at a loss, any input is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As @Belouccio answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59092604/angular-8-ng-build-throwing-mime-error-in-firefox-and-404-in-chrome) post, one hast to change base href="/myproject/" to base href="/" in your index.html in your docs folder on github.