# Angular 8 ng-build throwing MIME error in Firefox and 404 in Chrome

Tags: angular, github-pages, mime

After deploying my Angular app on github pages it will not render online at `www.https://www.lorem.com/`, the page is just blank and i have errors in the console.

On firefox it says:

[image]

On Chrome it says:

[image]

Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: Why was I voted down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like a problem with base href, cause there are no files in `www.illiteratiartandcowork.com/theotherspace/`, try to change `base href="/theotherspace/"` to `base href="/"` in your index.html in your docs folder on github.

From this url I get css file correctly (it also works for other files)
`https://www.illiteratiartandcowork.com/styles.a400f1df2c914132955e.css`